# How to navigate to "peer page" in Maui?

Tags: navigation, maui

I'm implementing a Maui app. I have two pages, that are two different ways to implement the same goal, the user may chose which one they prefer. I have a button on each page, that is supposed to switch between these two, so that the user can easily switch between the two views.
Let's call thes pages Page3a and Page3b.

Navigation takes user to Page1, then Page2, then say Page3a, so the navigation stack is Page1/Page2/Page3a.
When the user taps a button, I'd like to navigate to Page3b, with a resulting navigation stack Page1/Page2/Page3b.

I tried to use

```
Navigation.RemovePage(Page3a);
await Navigation.PushAsync<Page3b>(_vm.PartyId);
```

but I ended up with Page2 on screen.
Debugging into it I also found that after executing Navigation.RemovePage(Page3a) there are no pages in Navigation.NavigationStack - which is odd, possibly an error.

The question is, is it something that can be done? If not is there an alternative navigation approach to make it work? I don't want to use visibility to hide one version of screen contents or the other, because they are both quite heavyweight (meaning many items on, long time to load each).

Comment: Are you using MAUI's Shell? In that case, you need to use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` for navigation. Shell is the default when using the standard project template. Can you show more code? What's the structure of your pages/navigation?

Comment: Please explain the logic. The buttons are on page3a and page3b? so when you press the button on page3a you will go to page3b and vice versa?

May be you can RemovePage page3a from stack when you are actually are in page3b.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas correct, buttons are on Page3a and Page3b. The expected behaviour would be thet when their respective buttons are tapped, they remove themselves from the navigation stack and navigate to the other.

Comment: @ewerspej, yes, using MAUI Shell and Sharpnado's https://github.com/matt-goldman/Maui.Plugins.PageResolver.
In the past I found Shell nav cumbersome, hence the attempt at PageResolver.
Now, using shell navigation:
- Page1 is a shell page
- Registered Page2 for the route "Page1/Page2"
- Registered Page3a for the route "Page1/Page2/Page3a"
- Registered Page3b for the route "Page1/Page2/Page3b"
- Changed navigation on Page3b to
  Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../{nameof(Page3a)}")
  and it does attempt navigation to Page3a, which should be the answer.
I just need to sort param passing.

Comment: *"so the navigation stack is Page1/Page2/Page3a"* Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the routes, and on the exact commands used to navigate. You might have done a command that REPLACES nav stack contents? *"Is there an alternative navigation?"* Yes. `MainPage = new NavigationPage();` Don't use Shell features at all. Lower-level management of nav stack. More programming needed, but you are in control. YMMV * [OPINION] Mixing two different navigation approaches seems like a recipe for trouble. IMHO, Either do all navigation the way PageResolver says. Or do all Navigation the way shell nav doc says.